# How can I get a protocol working under GNU-EFI?

Tags: c, uefi, gnu-efi

I use GNU-EFI to develop UEFI apps. I have some trouble getting a protocol (EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL) working under GNU-EFI. My compiler says that it is undefined. Should I include something? I already included `efi.h` and `efilib.h`. Do I need more?

Code that I tried:

```
EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL shell;
```

The error that I got:

```
error: unknown type name ‘EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL’; did you mean ‘EFI_OPEN_PROTOCOL’?
  161 |  EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL shell;
```

Comment: Please provide the code you are trying to build, a description of what you expect it to do, and a description of what you are seeing instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL isn't part of the main UEFI interface, and is therefore not included in the main header files (e.g. `efi.h`) and not included in the main UEFI standard.

Instead, EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL is just an optional extension (that may not exist, and I'd assume is only likely to exist when a shell is being used and provides it), with its own separate standard and its own separate header file.

Assuming you're using GNU's tools; the right files to include are probably `efishellintf.h` and `efishellparm.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, GNU-EFI does not support EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL. It doesn't contain any related definitions about it.

If you want to use it with GNU-EFI, you can use [this header file from edk2](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/3806e1fd139775610d8f2e7541a916c3a91ad989/MdePkg/Include/Protocol/Shell.h) (put it in `inc` folder, for example, `inc/efishell.h`). Then include this header file in `inc/efi.h` and add these lines:

`lib/data.c`:

```c
EFI_GUID ShellProtocol = EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL_GUID;
```

`inc/efilib.h`:

```c
extern EFI_GUID ShellProtocol;
```

Rebuild your GNU-EFI and now you can use EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL by locating it first.

```c
EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL *SP;

uefi_call_wrapper(BS->LocateProtocol, 3, &ShellProtocol, NULL, &SP);
```

Comment: @Moldytzu I created a modified version of gnu-efi which supports EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL. You can try this at [https://github.com/kagurazakakotori/gnu-efi/tree/shell-protocol](https://github.com/kagurazakakotori/gnu-efi/tree/shell-protocol)

Answer (score 0):

The EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL is fully documented in the UEFI Shell Specification (currently v2.2) which can be downloaded at https://uefi.org/specifications

GNU EFI does not currently implement EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL or, indeed, all of the current UEFI Specification.  For a reference implementation of the UEFI Shell Specification look at the EDK11 ShellPkg source code.